# Appengine SDK 1.7.3 not detecting updated files

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I just updated to SDK 1.7.3 running on Linux. At the same time I switched to the SQLite datastore stub, suggested by the depreciation message.

After this, edits to source files are not always detected, and I have to stop and restart the SDK after updating, probably one time in ten. Is anyone else seeing this? Any ideas on how to prevent it?

UPDATE: Changes to *python* source files are not being detected. I haven't made any modifications to yaml files, and I believe that jinja2 template file modifications are being detected properly.

UPDATE: I added some logging to the dev appserver and found that the file I'm editing is not being monitored. Continuing to trace what is happening.

Comment: Which source files? Edits to `app.yaml` have always required a dev_appserver restart.

Comment: We are seeing the same thing. It doesn't always do it but it is annoying. Once a module has been imported it seems it doesn't always check for modifications.

Comment: Dave - good point and I've edited to make it clear it's python source files. Justin, did this start happening after the upgrade? Did you switch to SQLite at the same time? And are you using the Linux SDK?

Answer (score 3):

A similiar issue happens with appcfg.py in SDK 1.73, where it skips uploading some files sometimes.  It looks like this only happens if appcfg.py is run under python 2.7.
The workaround is to simply run appcfg.py under python 2.5. Then the upload works reliably.
The code uploaded can still be 2.7 specific - it is only necessary to revert 2.5 in the step of running the uploader function in appcfg.py.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this after the 1.7.3 update too, on Mac. I didn't change anything with the datastore. I'd say one in ten is about right.

edit:

There's a solution here that involves adding "self._dirty = True" to google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8383

Seems to work for some, haven't seen the problem since.